# Openlayer drupal module zipcode error

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am using openlayer drupal module. I am passing the zip code in url and getting zip code from url and map the location. Its working good for all zip code except 45150. 45150 is zip code of "Milford", but in map its shows me Topeka. Why its happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the OpenLayers module are you using? Also, what other modules?  It doesn't seem like there is enough information here to help you debug this problem.

The new [D7 Handbook page](http://drupal.org/node/1481374) might help but it's not that specific.

Comment: The latest dev version of OpenLayers is probably better. I think you're going to also need http://drupal.org/project/geocoder but not sure there is yet a clean solution for Drupal 7.

Comment: Thanks Mike... I am facing a very strange problem. When i clone default map its working fine but for any other map its not working....